# send data to android phone that if someone decompile my app should not be able to get that data

Tags: android

I want to send an apiKey(String value) to my app and want to restrict hacker not to get that api on decompiling the app.

Is there a way to send apiKey(String value) to android app without being hacked?.

Comment: Do you want only secure api key. what about your api urls?

Comment: actually there is no concern about the url(because that url is third party's url so anybody can get it). I only want to secure my key. So please tell how i can do volley request without knowing anybody. Don't worry i am making it simpler. User will get data through my API_KEY (by volley request) but this only possible if someone have API_KEY and i purchased for user. so basically i am afraid of stealing my API_KEY because any one can get it by decompiling my app so how i can make it secure?

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-secure-an-android-app--cms-26385

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-practices-for-developing-a-secure-Android-application  These links can be useful for you

Comment: Thanx Khemraj may it would be helpful

Comment: These links are helpful thank you

Comment: I posted these links in answer first, but stackoverflow does not allow link based answer, so it was deleted. :/

Comment: I don't know why, but it should well great job